Reuse variable with multiple trait types with different implementation
I have a reader variable which should be conditionally reassigned by another reader. But I'm using two traits, which is not supported in Rust. Defining a new trait using both traits is not an option as this is not compatible to the multiple traits anymore.
How to get this working?
use std::io::{BufReader, Read, Result, Seek};
use std::fs::File;

fn do_something_with_reader<R: Read + Seek>(reader: &mut R) {
    // ...
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut reader: Box<dyn Read + Seek> = Box::new(File::open("some_file.txt")?);
    if true /* some condition */ {
        // BufReader is for demonstration only. I'm using custom structs.
        reader = Box::new(BufReader::new(reader));
    }
    do_something_with_reader(&mut reader);
    Ok(())
}

The Box<dyn Read + Seek> doesn't work. How could this be done without losing compatibility to Read + Seek?
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78ce2e1b7f4dbbcd492c53895dabf39b
